# Cube rendering: Textures displaying incorrectly

Tags: java, textures, jmonkeyengine

I am trying to render a wall by creating 4 cubes next to each other, the problem comes when applying the texture - JME3 does render the cube and applies the texture but i am seeing the inside of the cube. Is this some form of "View" which i can change? If so, how?

Below is the code and an image of what i mean[image]

```
    Box ground = new Box(new Vector3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f), 5, 0,-5);
    Geometry groundPlane = new Geometry("GroundPlane", ground);
    Material groundMat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
    groundMat.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Brown);
    groundPlane.setMaterial(groundMat);

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Box wall = new Box(new Vector3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3f((float)i, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        Geometry wallFace = new Geometry("WallMesh", wall);
        Material wallSkin = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        Texture tex_ml = assetManager.loadTexture("Interface/Wall.png");
        wallSkin.setTexture("ColorMap", tex_ml);
        wallFace.setMaterial(wallSkin);
        rootNode.attachChild(wallFace);            
    }

    rootNode.attachChild(groundPlane);
```

Kind Regards

Aiden Strydom

***COMPLETED - FINAL CODE***

```
    Vector3f oldVec = Vector3f.ZERO;
    Vector3f newVec = Vector3f.ZERO;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        newVec = new Vector3f((float)i, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        Box wall = new Box(oldVec, newVec);
        Geometry wallFace = new Geometry("WallMesh", wall);
        Material wallSkin = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        wallSkin.setTexture("ColorMap", tex_ml);
        wallFace.setMaterial(wallSkin);
        //wallSkin.getAdditionalRenderState().setWireframe(true);
        oldVec = new Vector3f((float)i, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        rootNode.attachChild(wallFace);            
    }

    rootNode.attachChild(groundPlane);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your normals are pointing in opposite directions. Either check your rendering engine to see if you have reverse normals function, or you need to provide the vertices in reverse order.

Or try this method

```
Box wall = new Box(new Vector3f(i, 0.0f, 0.0f), 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I took your comment to heart and all it was is i was i was restarting at position `new Vector3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)` and creating a box the size of `new Vector3f((float)i, 0.0f, -1.0f)` which would create a box the size of the previous box (rendering over the previous box) plus 1 unit more... I had to store the location of the previous vector - So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Box` class your own, or provided by jmonkey?

If its your own, your triangle winding order would appear to be flipped.

Comment: Melak47 - No it's that of JME i am still way to a novice to right my own (i think)

Comment: what are the arguments for the Box constructor? You use -1.0 quite a bit there, if that is scaling that could cause your faces to flip